# what is libpq.so.5 and how to make it avaliable

Tags: linux, debian

When I am running my app to connect to PostgreSQL, it tell me `libpq.so.5` is not found. What I am wonder what is `libpq.so.5`? how to make `libpq.so.5` avaliable? What I am doing right now is to install postgresql using this commnad:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql -y
```

but this has a problem that I did not want to use postgresql database, I only want to make `libpq.so.5` avaliable, the posgresql takes too much space(>100MB). any other better way to make `libpq.so.5` avaliable? I am now using `Debian bullseye` with the docker base image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Debian, `libpq.so.5` (which is the shared library for postgresql client programs) is in the `libpq5` package, so to install it, run:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq5
```

From the package description:

```
$ apt-cache show libpq5
Package: libpq5
Source: postgresql-13
Version: 13.4-3
Installed-Size: 779
Maintainer: Debian PostgreSQL Maintainers <team+postgresql@tracker.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.25), libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.17), libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7),
         libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0)
Description-en: PostgreSQL C client library
 libpq is a C library that enables user programs to communicate with
 the PostgreSQL database server.  The server can be on another machine
 and accessed through TCP/IP.  This version of libpq is compatible
 with servers from PostgreSQL 8.2 or later.
 .
 This package contains the run-time library, needed by packages using
 libpq.
 .
 PostgreSQL is an object-relational SQL database management system.
```

BTW, you can use the `apt-file` command (which is in the `apt-file` package) to find which package a filename (or partial filename) belongs to.  e.g.

```
$ apt-file search libpq.so.5
libpq5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5
libpq5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5.12
```

Comment: BTW, if you want to install only the `psql` command (and all of its dependencies, like `libpq`) then install the `postgresql-client` package instead of the `postgresql` package.   Note that both of these packages just depend on specific versions of the packages (like  `postgresql-client-13` or `postgresql-13`), to make it easier to upgrade from one version of pg to another.